# 2 threads entering a locked block of code at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am attempting to allow only 1 thread at a time to enter a certain block of code thusly:

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message) {
    if (id != null) {
        id.ProcessMessage(message);

        lock(lockObject) {
            if (id.ScanCode.Length > 4) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Sometimes 2 threads get in there and both execute the code. I have confirmed this in the VS debugger. Sometimes only 1 thread gets in, which is good, but at least half the time, 2 threads get in -- never more than 2 it seems.

Inside that if-block I'm doing this:

```
id.ScanCode = string.Empty;
return;
```

To me it seems this should prevent the 2nd thread from entering, if it did get blocked. But maybe I'm doing this wrong. What's the simplest way to prevent the 2nd thread from getting in there? Could they be entering simultaneously?

Comment: I doubt how this could happen.. You already use Lock() two threads could not enter the code inside lock statement

Comment: Yet it is happening...confirmed in VS debugger.

Comment: *Every* thread that passes the `id != null` check will enter the locked code block at some point. They won't enter *at the same time*. If you only want some threads to enter, then you need some kind of conditional check.

Comment: either debugger lies or you are interpreting what you saw incorrectly

Comment: Most likely he misinterprets the debugger output.

Comment: This appears to be a window proc. Any window is owned by one particular thread, so it can't be multiple threads entering this code. It may look that way if you use Invoke, or similar.

Comment: @SweatCoder Can show a screenshot of the debugger where you see two threads?

Comment: Does `id.ProcessMessage()` do anything with `id.ScanCode`? If so, it should be invoked from inside the lock block as well.

Comment: Note: `lock` does not prevent same-thread code block re-entrancy.

Comment: You guys are correct, my flaw was trying to use id.ScanCode as my flag, when in fact that is a volatile variable, not threadsafe, and constantly changing. I had to use a local variable that only gets set INSIDE the locked code block and that solved everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lock does not prevent any number of threads from ever entering that block. It just delays them until it gets freed. It will only assure you that only one thread AT A TIME will enter that block of code. As soon as the first thread exists, the second will lock the code and run it. And so on...

If you need only the FIRST thread to execute that block of code, just set a flag once it first gets run and for the consecutive threads just check that flag first.

Comment: I used an add'l flag (private variable) besides just id.ScanCode and that seems to have solved it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am still pretty curious how more than one thread can run a WndProc.